WooCommerce and Elementor container sticky position not working properly
I'm trying to find out why, when I scroll down on a product page, the sticky product image gallery has a fixed mirror effect in the background.
Can someone please help me identify the problem and provide a fix for it?
This issue only happens with this specific element, which might be related to the gallery plugin I’ve added (which I really need). I would appreciate any guidance or solutions for this problem.
I found a workaround for the problem by making playing with the opacity of the element but I will still need to find out why it behaves like it does.
( I will not inject this CSS to let you see the problem as it is).


.elementor-element-9c6b0db {
    opacity: 1;
}


.elementor-element-9c6b0db:not(.elementor-sticky--active) {
    opacity: 1; 
}

.elementor-sticky--active {
    opacity: 1; 
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
}

.elementor-element-9c6b0db.elementor-sticky--active {
    opacity: 1;
}

.elementor-element-9c6b0db:not(.elementor-sticky--active) {
    opacity: 1; 
}

.elementor-sticky--active + .elementor-element-9c6b0db {
    opacity: 0; 
}



Link to the product page here:
